# psensor doesn't show charts on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lm-sensors, psensor

that is how psensor looks like in my system:
[image: psensor in ubuntu 18.04 doesn't show charts]
and that is how psensor should loo like:
[image: psensor in ubuntu normal look]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its a really silly thing - this happened to my system as well, and here's how to fix it.

1. Grab to top-right corner of the p-sensor window and expand it a little
2. Grab the left edge of the pane with the list of sensors, and drag it to the right.

If you shrink the psensor window, by grabbing the right edge and moving left for example, it will consume the space used by the plot and not leave a handle between the plot and the list of sensors that you can see.

---

AFAIK the problem only occurs the *second* time you run psensors (I reinstall often) - after that, it seems to retain the window size and position settings.

Comment: It really works. Expanding a window suddenly shows the chart.

Comment: @ValeryNoname  If this helped, please accept my answer!

Comment: @ValeryNoname I'll add a note to the question, but AFAIK the problem only occurs the second time you run psensors (I reinstall often) - after that, it seems to retain the window size and position settings.

Comment: Thanks!! I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 18.04 with Wayland/Gnome by turning off or on `Enable sensors logging` in the settings.  Also, your solution works and even simpler on my system is to drag the right side far to the left and back to where it started (same effect).